# Level of CSS specification

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand the specification of HTML elements through CSS. There are two different types that I am having trouble to differentiate. The difference is the blank between `a` and the class name `some-class`:

Case 1:

```
a .some-class {
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

Case 2:

```
a.some-class {
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

What is the difference between both? Is Case 2 more specific than Case 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Case 1** selects the class `some-class` which is nested within the `a` tag:

```css
a .some-class {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><p class="some-class">Some text</p></a> <!-- a .some-class -->

<a href="#" class="some-class"><p>Some text</p></a> <!-- a.some-class -->
```

**Case 2** selects the element `a` *with* the class `some-class`:

```css
a.some-class {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><p class="some-class">Some text</p></a> <!-- a .some-class -->

<a href="#" class="some-class"><p>Some text</p></a> <!-- a.some-class -->
```